# Connecting MPTT tree to a model.Model

Tags: django-models, django-mptt

I am trying to implement a MPTT tree such that

```
Degree (Bachelor,Masters,PhD,Diploma)
- Degree_Name (B.tech,B.A,.....M.tech....)
--Course_Specialization (Civil,Mechanical,...........Eng,.....etc..)
```

and I have a model

```
  class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name="Entity Name"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And `Course_Specialization` are saved as entities in `Entity` table.

Is there a way of dong this i.e the `MPTT` tree fetches `Course_Specialization` values from `Entity` table

I can't convert `Entity` table as a node of `MPTT` tree as it has other values as well.

Comment: maybe OneToOne reation will help?